# Run query with table name parameter

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

```
Dim tbl as String = Request.QueryString("tb") 'tb value = User
Dim sql As String = "Select * From @table Where @Col = @ColVal"
Dim para As New SqlParameter
para.ParameterName = "table"
para.Value = tbl

Dim paraArray1 As New SqlParameter
paraArray1.ParameterName = "@Col"
paraArray1.Value = "Name"

Dim paraArray2 As New SqlParameter
paraArray2.ParameterName = "@ColVal"
paraArray2.Value = "Stephen"
```

When I try to use DbDataAdapter to run the "sql" command, it gave me this error

> Must declare the table variable "@table".  Description: An unhandled
>   exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.
>   Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and
>   where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Must declare
>   the table variable "@table".

please advice what should I do to run the sql with given table name as parameter and avoid the sql injection. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Parameters are related to stored procedures, you can't specify them in the inline query. You need to concatenate the parameters in the query.

To avoid SQL injection, best approach is to use stored procedures but still if you need to use inline query, check the values before making inline query.

Answer (score 0):

Write parameter name of table correctly..

```
para.ParameterName = "@table"
```

Using `SqlParameter` avoid Sql Injection in some way as parameters are never inserted directly into statement.....

Answer (score 0):

Parameters is valid only for value. Change the SQL string :

```
Dim sql As String = String.Format("Select * From {0} Where {1} = @ColVal",tableName,ColName)
```

Comment: I see, thanks. However, does this way also avoid the sql injection?

Comment: @user1439709 - That's true but there is no alternative here (you want to generate dynamic sql text).